# Excel lookup using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I make `Timesheet!C2` display $10 and `Timesheet!C3` display $20?

[image]

[image]

So far I have this:

```
=VLOOKUP("base", Rates!A2:D4, 4, FALSE)
```

but I need it to also check that `Punch-in` from `Timesheet` falls in between `Start` and `End` from the `Rates` sheet.

I am totally open to abandoning the `VLOOKUP()` function so all suggestions are welcomed.

---

Data provided for easy copying.

| Punch-in | Punch-out | Hourly |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/21/2022 14:00 | 11/21/2022 22:00 |  |
| 1/10/2023 10:00 | 1/10/2023 18:00 |  |

| Key | Start | End | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| base | 1/1/2022 0:00 | 12/31/2022 23:59 | $10.00 |
| base | 1/1/2023 0:00 | 12/31/2023 23:59 | $20.00 |
| OT | 1/1/2010 0:00 | 12/31/2050 23:59 | $30.00 |

Comment: Using `SUMIFS` as detailed in the linked thread.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, I will mess around with `SUMIFS` later today. It looks promising!

Comment: You'll need to determine whether the row represents base or OT as well. Here's a demo with `SUMIFS` to get you started: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfviN.png

Comment: @BigBen `SUMIFS()` worked wonderfully. I cannot thank you enough! I really appreciate the conciseness.